# How to use Objective-C in C++ header?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I tried to do the following in the A.h file:

```
#include "Bar.hpp"

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

namespace foo 
{
  struct A : Bar::B
  {
    public:

    A() : Bar::B() {}

    id delegate;

    virtual void OnEvent(...);
  };
}
```

But I get zillion of errors like 'I dont know what NSString is'. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: What kind of source are you including it from? It will only work if the language is Objective C++ (not C, Objective C or plain C++).

Comment: The source, which is shown above, is from an .h file, which has a corresponding .mm implementation.

Comment: Presumably, you're also including it from other files. Are they all Objective C++ too? If you include it from any source files of other languages, then you'll get errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're including it in a `.cpp` file? Rename it to `.mm` (that's the correct file extension for Objective-C++).

Comment: Or one can set the file type under "Get Info".

Comment: No, it's a .h file. That .h file has a corresponding .mm impl.

Comment: Make sure that all files that #include/#import this one header are .mm

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use one of your Objective C classes inside your "regular" C++ class (as opposed to Objective C++) you could use [the trick described in this article](http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++), which boils down to including `<objc/objc-runtime.h>` instead of `<Foundation/Foundation.h>`, and using a wrapped `struct objc_object` in place of a "real" Objective C object.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
@class ABCWidget;
#else
typedef struct objc_object ABCWidget;
#endif

namespace abc
{
  class Widget
  {
    ABCWidget* wrapped;
  public:
    Widget();
    ~Widget();
    void Reticulate();
  };
}
```